# am Prove about set $X$ in vector space such that if $x,y \in X$ then $(x-y)/2 \in X$

Tags: vector-spaces

I trying to prove the following:

> Let $V$ be a real vector space and $X \subset V$ such that for every $x,y \in X$ is $\frac{x-y}{2} \in X$, then given $0 < \mu < \lambda$ is $\mu X \subset \lambda X$

I know that $0 \in X$ and I know how to prove it if $X$ was convex, but I don't see how to prove it with this apparently weak subtraction condition.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not true. Take $V=\Bbb R$, seen as a real vector space. Take $X=\Bbb Q$. Then you clearly have$$(\forall x,y\in X):\frac{x-y}2\in X.$$However, $2X\not\subset\pi X$.